# Updates to the Stack Overflow blog

Tags: discussion, blog

We've been busy working on an update for [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) and today we've pushed it live. As with most things software, this isn't something that's ever really done so we will be evolving things over time.

We're also changing the name to 'The Overflow'. We liked it so much for the newsletter we're trying it out here. It also fits better for our ambitions for the future of the blog being a home for all kinds of content - including the more *business* focused posts (currently the multi-lingual [Developer Hiring](https://stackoverflow.blog/talent/) blogs), which used to live elsewhere. The navigation is quite minimal currently but we can see this changing as the breadth of content continues to increase.

Finally, as it's all built with our [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) design system, you'll be getting a sneak-peak at the dark-mode friendly future we want to build out across all our sites.

I've been through some of the other threads with existing feedback but any new things or bug reports are most welcome!

Comment: Ooh, automatic dark mode.

Comment: It's amazing seeing Stacks used to its full potential. It's responsive and we get dark mode pretty much for free? What an incredible case study! Keep up the solid (and fassst) work. I can't wait to see this evolve.

Comment: Still no index, but at least there's now a reasonable way to find older posts.

Comment: No offence....but that site is hurting my eyes. The 3D printing picture is overwhelming and drowns out the contents.

Comment: _“a sneak-peak at the dark-mode friendly future we want to build out across all our sites”_ — Shouldn’t [Having a dark theme for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/289905) and all the MSO cross-site dupes be [meta-tag:status-planned] then?

Answer (score 8):

### The good news:

- **Pagination**! And it works! This is *long* overdue, but I'm nevertheless glad it's finally here.
- Pagination even does something sane in the URL.
- [**Search by author**](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/) is a nice addition.
- There's also a working **search** function, which is nice, also.
- No old links were broken; all the individual blog posts have stable URLs (which, as we all know, are [the cool ones](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)).

  A theme emerges: it's now possible to *find* things, which is an incredibly useful feature for an information resource like a blog. This is good work.

### The "meh" news:

- **Dark mode**. (Yeah, yeah, I know, some people *really* like this. I, on the other hand, tend to think it should be a browser or operating system feature, rather than one that is toggled per-website.)

### The bad news:

**It's hard to use.**  While it might look pretty, the overall presentation is cluttered, messy, and *inconsistent*, which makes it fundamentally difficult to use.

- Instead of presenting blog posts in a uniform manner, they're all crammed into different-sized blocks:

  [image]

  These block sizes suggest a differential weighting to the content, but there is no obvious reason why *"What is Rust and why is it so popular?"* should be weighted more heavily than *"How to create micro-interactions with react-spring: Part 1"*. Why are some of these things "more equal" than other things?
- Instead of ordering things in rows like the rest of the known universe, the presentation is organized first by *column*, and then by row. This is a case-study in sub-optimal, ineffective, and unexpected presentation of data. It also has the major downside of forcing the preview text into tiny little newspaper-style columns, which makes the text more difficult to read.

  [image]
- Because the author blurb comes *below* the preview text, which is of variable length, the placement of the author blurb varies from one blog post to the next, which makes it difficult to find at a glance, and also makes the page appear messy and non-uniform. Consider moving the author blurb up, since its size is vertically fixed (I hope).

  [image]
- The front page is *especially* cluttered, intermixing content in strange and confusing ways. We have blog posts of all different sizes, which are thrown right in with a "Most popular" table (containing...what? blog posts? of *more* different sizes?), and then a big banner-style table of Podcasts (which are...this time of *uniform* sizes?).
- Images of dubious applicability are consistently emphasized and prioritized over meaningful content. Coming up with a good, relevant image for technical blog posts is difficult, I know. You end up with something largely ornamental. That's why you shouldn't emphasize it over the text.
- Sometimes, the images change even for the same content. [First, we were playing Scrabble; now, we're...speaking in differently colored bubbles?](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/stackoverflowknows/)
- Speaking of the same content, there's no clear connection or theme between regular "columns" (e.g., #StackOverflowKnows, Code for a Living, and so on). As with a traditional print magazine, all articles from these "sections" should have some unifying theme grouping them together. I did discover the tags, which is thoughtful, but becomes all the more confusing when *some* tags have their own dedicated sub-sections (like [Podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/) and the [Newsletter](https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/)) that are easily accessible from the top navigation bar, whereas others (like #StackOverflowKnows) don't. The grouping of these should be emphasized, and it should also be possible to filter based on group, removing types of content that you don't care about or aren't interested in at the moment. At a minimum, there should be a tag page that shows all of the tags so that I can *find* them, without having to go through multiple pages of articles looking for new and interesting tags.
- Overall, the individual entry pages look and feel very nice. However, the tags presented there are inconsistent with the tags on the main index pages, not only in appearance (they aren't formatted like blue boxed tags, but simply as plain text), but also in content—the tags listed for [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/23/micro-interactions-with-react-spring-part-2/) are "animation" and "react", whereas when that article is listed on the index page, its only tag is [code-for-a-living](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-for-a-living).
- Speaking of individual entry pages, I think you're vastly over-promoting the Podcast. On [this blog entry page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/23/micro-interactions-with-react-spring-part-2/), for example, there are *two giant banners* linking the Podcast:

  [image]

  They're for the exact same podcast, and they contain almost exactly the same content. Why do we need both of them? Worse, the first one implies it is integral to the content of the blog post, since it precedes the "Tags:" list. The exact same problem is observed in [this blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/03/is-it-time-for-a-front-end-framework/).

Comment: I agree with over-promoting the podcast, but the rest of the stuff in the "bad" section doesn't bother me so much.

Comment: Solid feedback, thanks for taking the time to write. Taxonomy is something we're working on for sure. Agree about the podcast double-up (we were manually adding to articles, now it's automated). I've purged a few of them out the system.

Comment: What can I say, @S.S.Anne, I like consistency and favor readability/accessibility over presentation?

Comment: About the dark mode: isn't it tied to the operating system? At home I have a windows 10 pc with dark mode on and I saw dark mode enabled by default. But at work I have a mac with high sierra (so no dark mode) and I see the light version enabled by default.

Comment: @Kodos The operating system/browser can set it with an HTTP header.

Comment: @Cody Gray - author info now aligns to the bottom of each row. Hopefully easier to see at a glance now?

Answer (score 4):

Looks great!

Minor detail: In the "tags" section on the homepage it says *Der IT-Recruiting (German)* ... that is somewhat wrong (cause *der* is the pronoun for *Blog*, which is the word cut off). I'd propose just *IT-Recruiting (German)*.

Comment: Good spot & thank you. I've updated this.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, I like the new changes, but I'm experiencing some issues:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Whereas my saved name was shown as `S.S. Anne` before the change, it is now shown as `S.S.+Anne`.

Screenshot:

[image]

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Replies are shown improperly. For example, the second comment here is not a reply to the first ([ref](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/27/blog-contributor-guidelines)):

[image]

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Also, I've never been able to figure out how to add my user icon to my comments. How can I do that?

Comment: Let me look into the `+`, as for the avatar our blog provider Wordpress provides a service called [Gravatar](https://gravatar.com/) you can use (it'll work in other places around the web too)

Comment: @David Noticed another bug. Please take a look.

Comment: If you do a refresh, that should be fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @DavidLongworth Neither are. The second two comments on that blog post are shown as replies to mine but aren't.

Comment: Still not fixed itself, @S.S. Anne?

Comment: @DavidLongworth The second issue has been fixed, but the first hasn't.